# Getting users data from firebase database doesn't work after authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new in angular and firebase and trying to get users data to table only after succesful auth - if you log in correctly, the table shows the data, and if not, you can't see this data. I've tried to make simple firebase login and logout in my AuthService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private router: Router, private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  onLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function () {
        console.log('Succes');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  async onLogout() {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().signOut();
      this.router.navigate(['./']);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my UserService responsible for displaying users in the table:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchUsers() {
    let result = new Subject<User[]>();
    this.http
      .get('https://fir-login-1416c.firebaseio.com/users.json')
      .subscribe((users) => {
        let usersAr = Object.keys(users).map((id) => new User(users[id]));
        result.next(usersAr);
      });

    return result.pipe(take(1));
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    let postData: User = user;

    this.http
      .post<{ name: string }>(
        'https://fir-login-1416c.firebaseio.com/users.json',
        postData,
        {
          observe: 'response',
        }
      )
      .subscribe(
        (responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData.body.name);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  deleteUser() {
    // Later
  }
}
```

My firebase database rules looks like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth !== null",
    ".read": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

But probelm is when I log in with the correct data and navigate to page with users table I see empty table and console shows
[this errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMOZw.png).
It looks like the authentication didn't work at all or I just did something wrong.
If you have any suggestions on how to do this, give them to me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send some kind of authorisation headers with your request. Otherwise the database doesn't really know that your are authenticated.

I would suggest to use AngularFire not only for authentication but also for fetching data.

Comment: Thanks! I used AngularFire to post and fetch data and it works